# How to llst nodes by relating multiple other nodes

Tags: sql, neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4J and apologise if the question was titled poorly, but I want to  a node(phone) to another node(colours) which is the colours available for the phone. I need to list the phones which are available in both blue and purple and not individually. The following is what is what I have tried but it shows no changes are made. Can you not use AND with WHERE to declare two nodes?

```
MATCH (p:Phone)-[r:AVAILABLE]->(c:Colour)
WHERE c.name="blue" AND c.name="purple"
return p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will not be true because c.name cannot be both blue and purple at the same time. This is how you will get phones that are available in both blue and purple

> 1. Get all phones that has colour blue or purple
> 2. Collect all distinct colours as a set
> 3. Check that the each item on this set(colours) have blue or purple colour

```
WITH ["blue", "purple"] as blue_purple 
MATCH (p:Phone)-[r:AVAILABLE]-(c:Colour) 
    WHERE c.name in blue_purple
WITH blue_purple, p as phone, collect(distinct c.name) as colours
    WHERE size([co in colours WHERE co in blue_purple]) = 2
RETURN phone
```